# Acessing collections in a template rendered function

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to populate a javascript tag element, and want to do it on the template rendered call-back.

However, I am having trouble accessing collections data from this place. Even a very simple count function always return undefined.

```
Template.eventEdit.rendered = function() {
  alert(Tags.find().count());
}
```

What's wrong? Where is the right place to pre-populate a jquery element, using data from a meteor collection?

For reference, the actual code looks like this:

```
$('#inputTags').tokenInput( 
    '/tagsJSON',
    {
      propertyToSearch: "tag",
      theme: "facebook",
      prePopulate: JSON.stringify(Tags.find({_id: this.data._id},{fields: {"_id":1, "tag":1}}).fetch())

});
```

I am using Meteor 0.8.2. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you get if you run `Tags.find().count()` in the console?

Comment: It returns 0 or 3. I eventually traced it to a missing waitOn iron router. If the Tags collection is not subscribed, then the pre-populate will obviously not work.